# Copying values of HTML div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `<div>` elements that have the same structure, but with different `id`-s and `name`-s. I want to copy the values of one div into the other, preserving the attributes and copying only the `value` attributes.

I tried the following way:

```js
$('#current-1').html($('#next-1').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-1">
  <div id="current[1]_div1">Some text for current - div1</div>
  <div id="current[1]_someelement2">Some text for current - someelement2</div>
</div>
<div id="next-1">
  <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
  <div id="next[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
```

It works, but not as I want it to. The source for ouput looks like:

```
<div id="current-1">
 <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
 <div id="next[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
<div id="next-1">
 <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
 <div id="next[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
```

However, the preferred way is:

```
<div id="current-1">
 <div id="current[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
 <div id="current[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
<div id="next-1">
 <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
 <div id="next[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to somehow achieve this? The problem is that the `current` as well as `next` can have 10, 15 or 20 elements, depending on the type. That's why I think that it will be a bit difficult to refer to all childs.

Comment: Is the structure always the same? Also, how is this recursive copying?

Comment: @Luca, the structure is always identical, i.e. the elements that exist in current, exist in next as well. In here I just used one as example, but the structure is more complex

Comment: Why don't you just reference `current[1]_div1` and `next[1]_div1` directly? Your example does not indicate you can't do that.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to just increment the div counter? `div1` -> `div2`?

Comment: @Luca, my mistake, calling it "recursive".

Comment: @MátéSafranka have updated the example and explanation.

Comment: Does anybody understand what the OP wants? Or am I the only person with no clue what exactly is desired. His input and preferred way looks exactly the same.

Comment: @ibowankenobi, please, pay attention to the id-s of divs in preferred way and output.

Comment: So you want to change a current div's all descendant textNodes with the nodeValue of its nextElementSibling if any. If this is what you want, then I added one more solution. It is resource-wise light on the machine and recursive (if matching elements are found). If you also have nested elements with ids in them, setting innerHTML on the outer parent will change them, this way you only touch the text nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution that copies the `html()` of all the `children()` from an element to another, using `.each()` and using the `index` of each element:
(That's quite short, I don't even know what to comment in the code!)

```js
// Copy each of the childs of next in the childs of current
$('#current-1').children().each(function(index) {
  var next = $('#next-1').children()[index];
  $(this).html($(next).html());
});

// Output in console to see ids
console.log($('#current-1').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-1">
  <div id="current[1]_div1">Some text for current - div1</div>
  <label>Label for current</label>
  <div id="current[1]_someelement2">Some text for current - someelement2</div>
</div>
<div id="next-1">
  <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
  <label>Label for next</label>
  <div id="next[1]_someelement2">Some text for next - someelement2</div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly if you always have the same structure in your "current" and "next" elements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, will it be possible to find forkaround that it works to all possible elemnts and  not only div? I mean, for ex, if there is a label in between.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to the divs that you want to recursive copy so that you can later select them with DOM traversal order, then use `element.cloneNode(true)`

input:

```
<div class ="recursive" id="current-1">
  <div id="current[1]_div1">Some text for current</div>
</div>
<div class ="recursive" id="next-1">
  <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next</div>
</div>
```

Here is a function to copy the divs to a target div:

```
function rCopy(container){
    var toBeCopied = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("recursive"));
    return toBeCopied.reduce(function(ac,d,i,a){ac.appendChild(d.cloneNode(true));return ac;},container)
}
```

container is the div you want to copy the elements to. Beware to not append this container to the same document as duplicate id's will make a problem

Usage:

```
rCopy(document.getElementById("someContainer"))
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/LygpLcko/

If you want to copy the `text` nodes of a current div with the text nodes of its `nextElementSibling` recursively (including the parents children text nodes if any) then use a recursive function and combine with `requestAnimationFrame` to prevent blowing the stack. I went from top to bottom (previous sibling gets its contents from the next), you can go any direction and attach a callback when all is finished. Here is an example:

INPUT:

```
<div class ="recursive" id="current-1">
  <div id="current[1]_div1">Some text for current</div>
  <div id="current[1]_div2">Some text-2 for current
      <div id="current[1]_div3"> Some inner current <br>
          <span>inner inner content current</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class ="recursive" id="next-1">
  <div id="next[1]_div1">Some text for next-1</div>
  <div id="next[1]_div2">Some text-2 for next-1
      <div id="next[1]_div3"> Some inner next-1 <br>
          <span>inner inner content next-1</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class ="recursive" id="next-2">
  <div id="next[2]_div1">Some text for next-2</div>
  <div id="next[2]_div2">Some text-2 for next-2
      <div id="next[2]_div3"> Some inner next-2 <br>
          <span>inner inner content next-2</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the last div with id next-2 with class recursive wont be touched because it does not have a similar sibling. The function:

```
function rCopy(current,target){
    var sNodes = current.childNodes;
    var tNodes = target.childNodes;
    for (
        var i =0,s=sNodes[i],t=tNodes[i];
        i<sNodes.length;
        ++i,s=sNodes[i],t=tNodes[i]
    ) {
         if (s && t && s.nodeType === 3 && t.nodeType === 3) {
              s.nodeValue = t.nodeValue;
              continue;
         } else if (s && t) {
              !function(current,target){
                  window.requestAnimationFrame(
                      function(){rCopy(current,target)}
                  )
              }(s,t)
         }
    }
  target.nextElementSibling && target.nextElementSibling.className === "recursive" && window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){rCopy(target,target.nextElementSibling)})
}
```

Usage:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){rCopy(document.getElementById("current-1"),document.getElementById("next-1"))})
```

Once called by requestAnimationFrame, the chain will continue until no next element sibling is found.

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/LygpLcko/2/

Comment: Thanks. what if I know the id attribute, which is for sure different can I then apply your proposed function using getelementbyid()? And how can I specify the name of target div?

Comment: If you know the ids wont be a problem or the target document is different you can go ahead and use it. The container is any node that is in the DOM or not. Either pass it by `getElementById` or create one one the fly using `document.createElement` Do you want a fiddle?

Comment: do I get something wrong, or nothing happents, I mean in the console I have everything as in the input

Comment: Yes the console should put everything as in the input because you recursively copied them. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Probably you misunderstood it. I need to copy the values of next element into current, preserving the names of current element's child nodes

Comment: 1. Div nodes do not have value. What is value? Textcontent? You should perhaps edit that and say what exactly is "value". 2. Your original question was not asking this at all. It is certainly not clear for me. Perhaps edit it to underline. 3. What is next element? Again use a terminology that makes sense in DOM, next sibling? next element sibling? Next child?

Comment: Ok, I think I could understand a bit better what you want, I updated the answer.